# Loading a resource to a mutable bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-canvas, mutable

I am loading a bitmap from a resource like so:

```
 Bitmap mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.image);
```

What I want to do is make some changes to the bitmap before It gets drawn to the main canvas in my *draw* method (As it would seem wasteful to repeat lots of drawing in my main loop when it isn't going to change). I am making the changes to the bitmap with the following:

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(mBackground);
c.drawARGB(...); // etc
```

So naturally I get an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor
```

So to avoid that I made a copy of the bitmap so that it is mutable

```
Bitmap mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.image).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Which avoid the problem however it sometimes causes OutOfMemoryExceptions, do know any better ways of achieving what I want?

Comment: in case you need to handle all API levels, check out this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16314940/878126

Answer (score 24):

Use `decodeResource(Resources res, int id, BitmapFactory.Options opts)` and specify `inMutable` in the options.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Comment: Works, but needs at least API level 11.

Comment: I can confirm, that the API level is a problem there:(

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use [RapidDecoder](https://github.com/suckgamony/RapidDecoder).

```
import rapid.decoder.BitmapDecoder;

Bitmap mBackground = BitmapDecoder.from(res, R.drawable.image)
        .mutable().decode();
```

Works for API level 8.

Answer (score 0):

Instad of yours:

```
Bitmap mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.image);
```

Use:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inMutable = true;

Bitmap mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.image, options);
```