# How to draw a bitmap with transparency

Tags: android, bitmap

How to draw a bitmap with a given color set as transparent?
For example I want all white pixels to be transparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to check every pixel of image and change its color.
you will get your answer in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889667/making-bitmaps-specific-color-transparent)

Comment: This is the fastest way? I'm a bit shocked that there is no built-in function for that...

Answer (score 14):

You need to set the Alpha value for the paint you're passing to the Bitmap.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setAlpha%28int%29

Values vary from 0-255

EDIT:

```
Paint p = new Paint();
//Set Blue Color
p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
//Set transparency roughly at 50%
p.setAlpha(125);
```

Comment: I don't get it. How can I set some color to be transparent if there is only one parameter? To choose a color I need at least three parameters. Could You write a short example how to display a bitmap on the surface view with a transparent white color?

Comment: I should've replied to this sooner but here goes. p.setColor(Color.White) sets the color of your bitmap to white. Transparency is controlled by one value - aplha which goes between 0 & 255. 0 is completely transparent, 255 is completely opaque - hence p.setAlpha(125) is somewhere in the middle. Does that clear things up?

Comment: This just sets the entire bitmap to be semi-transparent it does not give the intended effect.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that the op wanted to make only one color transparent without affecting the other colors in the bitmap. I misunderstood what he was asking for. Sorry!

Comment: Oddly enough, while this answer failed to answer the OP's question, it did answer the one I googled for. :)  Thanks Manish!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is drawing in trasparent color on your canvas (drawing holes).
The bitmapu needs alpha channel.

```
    //Set transparent paint - you need all of these three
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT));
    paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    // Do you wanna soften?
    // Set paint transparency:
    // 0 = transparent ink, no visible effect
    // 255 = full ink, hole in the bitmap
    p.setAlpha(192);

    // Do you want some blur?
    // Set blur radius in pixel
    paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(10, Blur.NORMAL));
```