# Android: Cloning a drawable in order to make a StateListDrawable with filters

Tags: android, android-widget, drawable

I'm trying to make a general framework function that makes any Drawable become highlighted when **pressed/focused/selected/etc**.

My function takes a Drawable and returns a StateListDrawable, where the default state is the Drawable itself, and the state for `android.R.attr.state_pressed` is the same drawable, just with a filter applied using `setColorFilter`.

My problem is that I can't clone the drawable and make a separate instance of it with the filter applied. Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
StateListDrawable makeHighlightable(Drawable drawable)
{
    StateListDrawable res = new StateListDrawable();

    Drawable clone = drawable.clone(); // how do I do this??

    clone.setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    res.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed}, clone);
    res.addState(new int[] { }, drawable);
    return res;
}
```

If I don't clone then the filter is obviously applied to both states. I tried playing with `mutate()` but it doesn't help..

Any ideas?

**Update:**

The accepted answer indeed clones a drawable. It didn't help me though because my general function fails on a different problem. It seems that when you add a drawable to a StateList, it loses all its filters.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to drawables loosing filters? I've run into same issue :( I ended up generating other image from source image by cloning Bitmap and applying filter pixel-by-pixel. Yes, this is inefficient, but I have just a bunch of small images processed once.

Comment: I couldn't solve it with StateListDrawable, but if you're not using StateListDrawable and still losing your filters, make sure your bitmaps are mutable. There are good related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499637/drawable-setcolorfilter-not-working-on-android-2-1 , also I've discovered that LightingColorFilter works in places where PorterDuff fails.. lovin this android :)

Comment: a great answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889415/adding-a-color-filter-to-a-drawable-changes-all-buttons-using-the-same-drawable

Comment: There is a similar side effect triggered by `ImageView.setImageDrawable`, which I was able to work around thanks to the accepted answer.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing and it works as expected somehow, the ColorFilter did not get lost...
The difference is that I did mutate the drawable.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Drawable clone = drawable.getConstantState().newDrawable();
```

Comment: Thanks! This method seems to clone a drawable successfully. The function I was trying to write though does not work.. It seems that when a drawable is inserted into a StateList it loses its filters :(

Comment: +1 for helping me fix a very strange error in MapView where re-using a Drawable from the ItemizedOverlay in an AlertDialog made the ItemizedOverlay move when triggered.
Making a new instance of the Drawable fixed the problem.

Comment: Do to worked correctly, if we try use setAlpha method. In this case both drawable change bitmap. 

Then I get first drawable as: getResources().getDrawable(), second as: getResources().getDrawable().mutate().

Comment: Thanks a lot, it fixed the problem I had when I applied a bounding function, from the API Mapsforge. Now I can succesfully use the drawables everywhere!

Comment: Now i can deep clone BitmapDrawables and NinePatchDrawables
THANKS

Comment: @Flavio - I tried this with a color filter, but it colored all instances of my drawable! Turns out it looks lik you have to use `.mutate()` (see my answer).

Comment: Aggree with @PeterAjtai, it works but colored all instances of my drawables... (See PeterAjtai answer)

Comment: I have a LayerDrawable, which I wanted to change the colorfilter of one of its inner drawable. I tried to use this, but it didn't work. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Will there a problem since .getConstantState() is nullable?

Answer (score 117):

If you apply a filter / etc to a drawable created with  `getConstantState().newDrawable()` then all instances of that drawable will be changed as well, since drawables use the `constantState` as a cache!

So if you color a circle using a color filter and a `newDrawable()`, you will change the color of all the circles.

If you want to make this drawable updatable without affecting other instances then, then you must mutate that existing constant state.

```
// To make a drawable use a separate constant state
drawable.mutate()
```

For a good explanation see:

http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()

Comment: In fact mutate() does return the same exact same instance, but its internal state is changed so applying a color filter will not impact other instances. Can you review and fix your answer?

Comment: @clemp6r if you don't use mutate all the instances of the color change - you need to call mutate in order to only change the color of the clone

Comment: Check the [API ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()) ("Make this drawable mutable. - Returns this drawable") and the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.2.2_r1.2-robolectric-0/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.java#426) ("return this"). Calling mutate() is required, but the returned instance is the same. This does not create a clone, this only changes the internal state of the drawable instance to allow modifying it without impacting other instances of the same drawable.

Comment: Well I don't know about the question, but this answer does the exact thing I needed... tU

Comment: I am encountering this very problem only on Lollipop, but it used to work fine even on KitKat. It is a very strange issues but thanks for the pointer on mutate()

Comment: Those are the best Links, ones which you gave for reference

Comment: Does using this method ("mutate") disable the caching caching of drawables via getResources().getDrawable ?

Answer (score 22):

This is what works for me.

```
Drawable clone = drawable.getConstantState().newDrawable().mutate();
```

Comment: YES I don not know WHY but only this combination newDrawable() and mutate() works for me any other single mutate() or single newDrawable() doesn't work correctly for me

Answer (score 12):

This is my solution, based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6071813/2075875).

The idea is that `ImageView` gets color filter when user touches it, and color filter is removed when user stops touching it. Only 1 drawable/bitmap is in memory, so no need to waste it. It works as it should.

```
class PressedEffectStateListDrawable extends StateListDrawable {

    private int selectionColor;

    public PressedEffectStateListDrawable(Drawable drawable, int selectionColor) {
        super();
        this.selectionColor = selectionColor;
        addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, drawable);
        addState(new int[] {}, drawable);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onStateChange(int[] states) {
        boolean isStatePressedInArray = false;
        for (int state : states) {
            if (state == android.R.attr.state_pressed) {
                isStatePressedInArray = true;
            }
        }
        if (isStatePressedInArray) {
            super.setColorFilter(selectionColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        } else {
            super.clearColorFilter();
        }
        return super.onStateChange(states);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStateful() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
Drawable drawable = new FastBitmapDrawable(bm);
imageView.setImageDrawable(new PressedEffectStateListDrawable(drawable, 0xFF33b5e5));
```

Comment: Works for me also! Thats an interesting solution, thanks!)   P.S. android sucks, such bad not properly working API :(

Comment: I think this is the best solution by far to solve bugs in (StateListDrawable + BitmapDrawable)!

Answer (score 1):

I answered a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571706/1128543)

Basically it seems like StateListDrawables indeed lose their filters. I created a new BitmapDrawale from a altered copy of the Bitmap I originally wanted to use.

Answer (score 1):

Get clone drawable using `newDrawable()` but make sure it is mutable otherwise your clone effect gone, I used these few lines of code and it is working as expected. `getConstantState()` may be null as suggested by annotation, so handle this RunTimeException while you cloning drawable.

```
Drawable.ConstantState state = d.mutate().getConstantState();
if (state != null) {
    Drawable drawable = state.newDrawable().mutate();
}
```

Comment: This worked, but you don't need to mutate it.

Answer (score 0):

```java
Drawable clone = drawable.mutate().getConstantState().newDrawable().mutate();
```

in case `getConstantState()` returns `null`.