# How do I made a deep copy a BitmapDrawable?

Tags: android

I'm having trouble cloning a BitmapDrawable. I tried the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979440/android-cloning-a-drawable-in-order-to-make-a-statelistdrawable-with-filters) but it creates a "shallow" copy, and I need a "deep" copy so I can alter the pixels in the clone without affecting the original.

I also tried this:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = bdOriginal.getBitmap();
    BitmapDrawable bdClone = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true));
```

But it seems to create an immutable clone even though I set the mutable parameter in Bitmap.copy() to "true". That is, color filters don't appear to change the clone. Am I doing it wrong? (EDIT: I used the debugger to confirm bitmap.mIsMutable = true)

To summarize, I need a clone of a BitmapDrawable that can be altered with color filters without affecting the original. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try with the drawable method `mutable()`.

Comment: Thanks, but the BitmapDrawable is still not affected by the color filter. :(  I know the filter is working because it works on the original bitmap and the shallow copy.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create new `Bitmap` of the same size.
2. Create canvas for this new `Bitmap`
3. Draw your first `Bitmap` into this canvas.

Example:

```
Bitmap copy = Bitmap.createBitmap(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), original.getConfig());
Canvas copiedCanvas = new Canvas(copy);
copiedCanvas.drawBitmap(original, 0f, 0f, null);
```