# Adding a color filter to a Drawable changes all Buttons using the same Drawable

Tags: android

I have a screen where multiple Buttons use the same background Drawable. I have reusable code I use in various projects to add an OnTouch listener that adds a gray color filter while a button is being touched. That usually works fine, but in this case ALL the buttons are tinted when any of them is pressed.

I see an explanation in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html:

> Note: Each unique resource in your project can maintain only one
>   state, no matter how many different objects you may instantiate for
>   it. For example, if you instantiate two Drawable objects from the same
>   image resource, then change a property (such as the alpha) for one of
>   the Drawables, then it will also affect the other.

The suggested solution is to use a TweenAnimation, which does not seem to work with color filters.

I also saw [Android: Cloning a drawable in order to make a StateListDrawable with filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979440/android-cloning-a-drawable-in-order-to-make-a-statelistdrawable-with-filters) which suggests using drawable.getConstantState().newDrawable(). This does not seem to make a difference. I'm guessing that as long as the same physical image file is used, all Drawables will be affected by a change to any other Drawable using the same resource.

What solution is there, other than creating a second background image to show the pressed state? It would be nice to have a simple programmatic solution I can add to my code and use in every project.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Example that should work for you:

```
Drawable buttonBackground = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg);
buttonBackground = buttonBackground.mutate();

//Set your filter here
```

Comment: I had the same problem using Overlays with the same Drawable and a different ColorFilter on a MapView. mutate(); fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Note that this only works if you call getDrawable.  If you've cached the drawable in a variable and call mutate() on it then they will still share the state.

Comment: I was getting crazy with this, this solved  the problem, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Android GUI handing is packed with silly timethieves like this. Hopefully, Google will create better turnover in the future so that they can afford professional programmers. Note that getDrawable is deprecated, modified solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wanted to use StateListDrawable using same drawable and this solved it! This is from Android documentation: 

_Make this drawable mutable. This operation cannot be reversed. A mutable drawable is guaranteed to not share its state with any other drawable.This is especially useful when you need to modify properties of drawables loaded from resources. By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive the same modification._