# Setting background colour on one object, changes another object

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-drawable

I have a TextView with a drawable as background. Using a StateListDrawable object I'm trying to set the background colour programmatically, but I'm running into unexpected behaviour: I set the colour in one object, and it changes in another. This should be impossible.

The relevant code:

```
    GradientDrawable notPressed = (GradientDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rectangle);
    GradientDrawable isPressed = (GradientDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rectangle);
    isPressed.setColor(util.getColour(api, this));

    StateListDrawable bg = new StateListDrawable();
    // bg.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, isPressed);
    bg.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, notPressed);

    textView.setBackgroundDrawable(bg);
```

The drawable:

```
<shape  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/divider" />
<solid android:color="@color/background_button" />
</shape>
```

`util.getColour` returns a colour resource based on the value of api.

The strange thing is that in the above code the colour of the `isPressed` drawable is set, but after that this drawable is not used. Instead only the `notPressed` drawable is added to the background of the textView.

But the background colour of the textView becomes the colour of the `isPressed` drawable instead! This should be impossible, as they should be two different objects, even if they are created from the same drawable resource.

Comment: check if `notPressed!=isPressed` I suspect that both are the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that when you get a resource you get the same reference to it. So `notPressed` and `isPressed` are the same object. I believe there's a clone operation somewhere...

Edit:

Yep, you have to call `mutate()` on the drawable before you modify it. See [Adding a color filter to a Drawable changes all Buttons using the same Drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889415/adding-a-color-filter-to-a-drawable-changes-all-buttons-using-the-same-drawable).

Answer (score 0):

Android uses the same object for drawable resources unless you specify that you need a new copy of it.

you can use this code to solve this issue:

```
Drawable isPressed  = notPressed.getConstantState().newDrawable();
```