# Altered GradientDrawable gets unwantedly reused in different places

Tags: android, layout, drawable, shapedrawable

I have a ShapeDrawable **drawable/my_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
       android:color="#FFFF00" />
    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

which I use as background of some `TextView`s at several places in my app. Like in **layout/my_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout...>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tag"
        android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap"
        android:text="Some text"
    />
<!-- other tags -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

or in a layout which gets used as list item **layout/my_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout...>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:background="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap"
    />
<!-- other tags -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, when I alter the color of the shape programmatically inside my `ArrayAdapter` of my list, the background of the `TextView` inside a fragment at a **totally different place in my app** gets the same color like the last item in my list! From that time on the shape with the altered color gets used in all other activities which have my_fragment.xml in their layout.

```
holder.subject = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subject);

GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)holder.subject.getBackground();
bgShape.setColor( position % 2 == 0 ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE );
```

**How is that possible and how can I avoid that "reuse" behavior?**

Here is the code of my array adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder; // to reference the child views for later actions

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = 
            (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, null);
        // cache view fields into the holder
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.subject = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subject);
        // associate the holder with the view for later lookup
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        // view already exists, get the holder instance from the view
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)holder.subject.getBackground();
    bgShape.setColor( position % 2 == 0 ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE );
    holder.subject.setText(getItem(position));
}

// somewhere else in your class definition
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView subject;
}
```

Comment: I have the impression, that  `mutate` could solve my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979440/android-cloning-a-drawable-in-order-to-make-a-statelistdrawable-with-filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use `bgShape.mutate().setColor(..)`

Also see

- [Android: Cloning a drawable in order to make a StateListDrawable with filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979440/android-cloning-a-drawable-in-order-to-make-a-statelistdrawable-with-filters#comment27275257_7980637)
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate%28%29