# How to set tint of vectorDrawable without modifying the original drawable?

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to use SVG file in my View class, and the problem I am running into is:
When I set the tint color of my VectorDrawable like this:

```
var d = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon)
var vDraw = VectorDrawable()
vDraw  = d as VectorDrawable
DrawableCompat.setTint(vDraw , Color.RED)
vDraw.draw(canvas)
```

I am ending up in modifying the original drawable. Is there a way I can do that in code without modifying the original SVG?

Comment: you have to mutate() your `Drawable` first

Comment: Thanks, that works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Cloning a drawable in order to make a StateListDrawable with filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979440/android-cloning-a-drawable-in-order-to-make-a-statelistdrawable-with-filters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the drawable `mutate()` method. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#mutate()):

> Make this drawable mutable. This operation cannot be reversed. A
>   mutable drawable is guaranteed to not share its state with any other
>   drawable. This is especially useful when you need to modify properties
>   of drawables loaded from resources. By default, all drawables
>   instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you
>   modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive
>   the same modification. Calling this method on a mutable Drawable will
>   have no effect.

And since you want to tint your drawable, you need to use also the `DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable)`. This will allow:

> Potentially wrap {@code drawable} so that it may be used for tinting
>   across the different API levels, via the tinting methods in this
>   class.

Applying this to your code:

```
var drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon)
drawable = drawable.mutate();
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable , Color.RED)
drawable.draw(canvas)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.This helped.