# Cannot crop Bitmap

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to crop and scale given bitmap,But only scaling works.
What am I doing wrong?

```
private Bitmap CropAndShrinkBitmap(Bitmap io_BitmapFromFile, int i_NewWidth, int i_NewHeight) 
{
    int cuttingOffset = 0;
    int currentWidth = i_BitmapFromFile.getWidth();
    int currentHeight = i_BitmapFromFile.getHeight();

    if(currentWidth > currentHeight)
    {
        cuttingOffset = currentWidth - currentHeight;
        Bitmap.createBitmap(i_BitmapFromFile, cuttingOffset/2, 0, currentWidth - cuttingOffset, currentHeight);
    }
    else
    {
        cuttingOffset = i_NewHeight - currentWidth;
        Bitmap.createBitmap(i_BitmapFromFile, 0, cuttingOffset/2, currentWidth, currentHeight - cuttingOffset);
    }
    Bitmap fixedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(i_BitmapFromFile, i_NewWidth, i_NewHeight, false)  ;

    return i_BitmapFromFile;
}
```

The description say that: "createBitmap Returns an immutable bitmap ".
What is that mean? and is it the cause to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cropping likely works fine, but the resulting `Bitmap` object that is cropped is **returned** from `createBitmap()`, the original object is not modified (as was mentioned, because the `Bitmap` instance is immutable).  If you want the cropped result, you have to grab the return value.

```
Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(i_BitmapFromFile, cuttingOffset/2, 0, currentWidth - cuttingOffset, currentHeight);
```

Then you can do any further work you would like with that result.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Bitmaps are by default "immutable", meaning you can't alter them. You need to create a "mutable" bitmap, which is editable.

Check out these links on how to do so:

[BitmapFactory.decodeResource returns a mutable Bitmap in Android 2.2 and an immutable Bitmap in Android 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349075/bitmapfactory-decoderesource-returns-a-mutable-bitmap-in-android-2-2-and-an-immu)

http://sudarnimalan.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-convert-immutable-bitmap-into.html