# Creating canvas from loaded PNG in Android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, png

I'm trying to create a canvas from a PNG file that I have loaded into a bitmap, but it gives an error. Here's the code:

```
public Bitmap CABINET_Bitmap;

AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
inputStream = assetManager.open("background.png");
CABINET_Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

// Next line gives error
Canvas cv = new Canvas(CABINET_Bitmap);
```

If I create the bitmap, rather than load it in, by doing:

```
CABINET_Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 640, Config.RGB_565);
Canvas cv = new Canvas(CABINET_Bitmap);
```

Then the canvas creation works. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states:

> Construct a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into. The bitmap
>   must be mutable.
>
> The initial target density of the canvas is the same as the given
>   bitmap's density.

So what I'm assuming is `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` is returning an immutable bitmap while `Bitmap.createBitmap()` is return a mutable one.  Instead, use `BitmapFactory.Options` and set `inMutable` to true.

```
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inMutable = true;
CABINET_Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, o);
Canvas cv = new Canvas(CABINET_Bitmap);
```

See if that works.

Comment: Sounds great!  Unfortunately, though my intellisense shows me an "inMutable" property, when I run the line "o.inMutable = true;" I get an error:  NoSuchFieldError...

Comment: D'oh.  I just noticed it was added in API 11.  Well, I'm pretty sure that it's the problem.  Thus, you need to convert the bitmap from immutable to mutable.  http://www.anddev.org/how_to_modify_the_image_file-t513.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349075/bitmapfactory-decoderesource-returns-a-mutable-bitmap-in-android-2-2-and-an-immu seem to be good places to start.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Brilliant, I should be able to fix it then.  Thanks for your help.  Saved me several hours of banging my head against the desk.