# Draw bitmap on canvas

Tags: android

I tried searching for a relevant example but found none, so I'll try to be as precise as I can.

Back in the gingerbread era I made a draw bitmap to canvas code that worked flawlessly and here it is.

```
//this one is drawing the background for my picture
mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.base);

//setting a new canvas
mComboImage = new Canvas(mBackground);

//adding another bitmap to the canvas, don't worry about the size or the i variables 
mBackImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.base);
      mBackImage=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackImage, size, 105, false);
      mComboImage.drawBitmap(mBackImage, 100f+1f*size*i, 170f, null);
      mBackImage.recycle();

//this is setting my background for an icon to the completed image
Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),mBackground);
                aaa.setBackground(d);
```

anyways the code doesn't seem to fit now. One problem I have faced is converting the bitmap into mutable which you can check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349075/bitmapfactory-decoderesource-returns-a-mutable-bitmap-in-android-2-2-and-an-immu) if you are stuck on it as I was for a while.

My problem is that the background is perfectly drawn but the mBackImage doesn't show up at all.
What worries me more is that this used to work perfectly before.

I really have tried searching for a newer explanation but haven't really found any on stackoverflow so

Comment: Hard to say. Try to make sure mBackImage actually has something inside by compress it into output file stream as well as 100f+1f*size*i gives some real offset as well as 170f, because you should not have these kind of values hardcoded instead use dimens from resources.

Answer (score 0):

I drew bitmap as background image for my app as well. I used: setBackgroundDrawable() instead of setBackground() in your last statement.

Also, when preparing the bitmap, I set two options:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inInputShareable=true;  
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.image1), options);
```

You can give it a try.

Comment: no this one doesn't help either, also I used setBackground because it says that setbackgrounddrawable is deprecated