# Convert immutable Bitmap file to mutable Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, immutability, mutable

A:

```
 Bitmap immutableBmp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),R.drawable.sample);
 mutableBitmap=immutableBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

B:

```
Bitmap immutableBmp= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
mutableBitmap=immutableBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

C:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inMutable=true;
myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);
```

A works but B and C don't. I am trying to convert an immutable bitmap to mutable. It works on resource images but not file images. What's the problem?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Doesn't work, hm? What does this mean exactly? A wild guess....your path is wrong.

Comment: Sorry @JohnSaunders, i thought i should be polite haha, thanks for informing

Comment: @ElDuderino The image from file does show up in the imageview just tat i am not able to draw on the image anymore. What's wrong?

Comment: @Alex: if you read the link, you'll find that politeness is nice when you're having a conversation. But we're not having a conversation here. Just Q&A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem! All of the 3 methods above are working, there was a problem with the resolution of my image, so I thought the code didn't work and it was not mutable but I was wrong. Here is another solution to change immutable image to mutable.

[BitmapFactory.decodeResource returns a mutable Bitmap in Android 2.2 and an immutable Bitmap in Android 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349075/bitmapfactory-decoderesource-returns-a-mutable-bitmap-in-android-2-2-and-an-immu)

Answer (score 13):

Found this:

```
Bitmap bmp_Copy = bmp_Base.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).