# Loading a bitmap with ImageDecoder from URI and adding text

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imagedecoder

In my activity, I want to modify an image to add a text on it.

The image is selected in the galery or taken with the camera and then stored in a file in a previous activity. Then the uri of that file is passed through extras.

Now I try to add a string on top of the image like so:

```
try {
        modifyThePic(imageUri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here is the function's body:

```
public void modifyThePic(Uri imageUri) throws IOException {

    ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
    Bitmap bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(10);
    canvas.drawText("Some Text here", 0, 0, paint);

    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //image is the imageView to control the result

}
```

The expected behaviour would be to display the image with "Some Text here" on top of it. But instead there is nothing displayed, however the app doesn't crash.

While debugging, I come across an error that appears between the

> Bitmap bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);

and the

> Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

here is the error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.emergence.pantherapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_20200829_181926_7510981182141824841.jpg

I suspect that I missuse the "ImageDecoder" as it's my first time using it. More precisely, I was not able to let the "decodeBitmap" method in onCreate, Android Studio was telling me that it could not be in the "main thread", I am not familiar at all with threading. Moving it in a dedicaded function fixed this but maybe am I supposed to do something else and it's the root of the problem.

**My questions:**
Am I using the right tools to modify the file and add the text on it ?
If yes, what do I do wrong ?
If no, what library/tools should I look into to do this task ?

Thank you,

**EDIT: ADDITONAL ANSWER ELEMENTS**

As both @blackapps and @rmunge pointed out, I was not getting a legit URI but instead a file path. The easy fix for my problem was to get the URI from the path using this code:

```
Uri realuri = Uri.fromFile(new File("insert path here")));
```

Additionaly to edit the bitmap, it must be made mutable which is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425789/convert-immutable-bitmap-file-to-mutable-bitmap) for example.

The final function to extract the bitmap from the URI and adding text on top of it is this one:

```
public void modifyThePic(Uri imageUri) throws IOException {

    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    InputStream input = cr.openInputStream(imageUri);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(300);

    int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2); //just some operations to center the text
    int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2)) ;

    canvas.drawText("SOME TEXT TO TRY IT OUT", xPos, yPos, paint);

    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

Comment: You should tell us wich statement causes the file not found exception. Be precise!

Comment: If you have a nice uri then open an input stream for it and use BitmapFactory.decodeStream() to make your bitmap.

Comment: I don't know exactly what is the statement, here is the full line:
2020-08-29 19:53:40.018 4773-4773/com.emergence.pantherapp W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.emergence.pantherapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_20200829_195338_7754310163132666088.jpg

Ok, I'm trying to open an input stream and come back

Comment: `imageUri` Is that an uri you obtained from the gallery? What is the value of imageUri.toString()? Please tell.

Comment: In the previous activity, I get an image from the camera or the gallery (users choice), then I store this image in a file that I create. And then when I go to the next activity, I pass this uri through putExtra.
The value of imageUri on my last test is:
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.emergence.pantherapp/files/Pictures/JPEG_20200829_200756_7382569580564697486.jpg

Which actually works fine if I just want to display the unmodified picture into an imageview with image.SetImageUri(myURI).

Comment: `In the previous activity, I get an image from the camera or the gallery` Please post only one scenario. Not gallery and camera. Too complicated. `then I store this image in a file that I create. `. Why would you make a copy of a file the user choosed from the gallery? Use the uri you got from the gallery instead for creating the bitmap.

Comment: `The value of imageUri on my last test is: /storage/emulated/0/Android/dat.....` That is no uri. That is a file system path.

Comment: Ok I need to do some research, I really thought that the URI was the absolute path, that's probably my big confusion. The reason I copy the image is because when it's modified, I don't want the original file to be modified as well. Thank you for your help so far, I'll make my research, try a few things and get back here to validate and add answer elements.

Comment: If you want to modify then load from obtained uri and save to a new file system path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your URI is wrong. It has to start with file:///

Comment: When I use this URI to just display the unmodified picture into an imageview with image.SetImageUri(myURI) it works fine, shouldn't it work fine as well for the ImageDecoder.createSource ?

Comment: No. As you should use a content uri you can read in the message. Not a file uri.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for clarification, I though URI and Absolute path were the same thing, that's my big confusion. I'll do some research and get back to validate etc.