# Having problems using setPixel() method

Tags: android, image, image-processing, pixel

Can someone explain me the way `setPixel()` method works in Android? I am trying to replace some pixels on a bitmap. I extract them by using `getPixel()` method and their individual colors, eg.`green = Color.green(a[i][j]);`, but I cannot set them new values back, so as to show the processed image onscreen.

Edit: This is where some of the processing occurs. I try to algorithmically convert to grayscale

```
 for (int i = 0; i < grayWidth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grayHeight; j++) {
                a[i][j] = myImage.getPixel(i, j);
                red = Color.red(a[i][j]);
                green = Color.green(a[i][j]);
                blue = Color.blue(a[i][j]);
                gray = (red + green + blue) / 3;
                a[i][j] = gray;
            }
        }
```

and then replace pixels:

```
for (int m = 0; m < grayHeight; m++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < grayWidth; n++) {
                grayScale.setPixel(m, n, a[m][n]);
            }
        }
```

and finally show it on-screen

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(grayScale);
```

Sorry for not explaining it thoroughly in the first place/

Comment: What si the error message? And parts of code where you get and set the Pixels.

Comment: @DavidK The processed image just isn't there. The app processes it but the end result won't show up on screen by using drawBitmap

Comment: Do you use try / catch clause to catch the exceptions? They might not crash your app, but still might occur. Also, give us some code..

Comment: Did you set grayWidth/grayHeight ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes by using `int grayHeight = myImage.getHeight();` and
        `int grayWidth = myImage.getWidth();`

Answer (score 0):

1. Why posts questions without any code? Put yourself in our position, how can we help you, if we do not know what you are trying to do? You're only presenting your problem in English language, which does not equal to programming language in most cases. We want to see the latter, supported with english description of what you are doing and what's going on.
2. Based on provided information and [Android Dev Page for Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixel(int,%20int,%20int)), I can assume that your BitMap image might not be **mutable**. This would throw then `IllegalStateException`, but without seeing your LogCat / Code, I cannot be sure, whether this is the case.
3. If the BitMap indeed is immutable, then you can try and look at [converting immutable bitmap to mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349075/bitmapfactory-decoderesource-returns-a-mutable-bitmap-in-android-2-2-and-an-immu/16314940#16314940) and try again.

Comment: I saw, but there is no try / catch clause to determine whether setPixel is throwing something.  Also on the Android Dev page I linked in my answer, you have a method `setPixels()` which takes in an Array, so you don't need to iterate over each pixel.

Comment: Ok i used setPixels, but I get the following error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <= bitmap.width(). The problem is that after debugging the app, the variable values match the image I am using. My example is a 20x12px image. If you check the code I've posted above, by using this line `grayScale.setPixels(b, 0, grayWidth, 0, 0, grayWidth, grayHeight);` should do the job, right?