# Resaving combined Bitmaps

Tags: android, file, bitmap

I am trying to open a bitmap that has already been stored in SdCard as follows:

```
    String imageFilePath= "/sdcard/SoftCopy/"+mybitmap.png;
BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap loadedWork= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath, bmpFactoryOptions);
```

I have a second Bitmap named currentWork. This bitmap is actually the current drawing that has been done. I have combined two bitmaps as follows:

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(loadedWork);
c.drawBitmap(currentWork, 0, 0, null); //so that currentWork get drawn on loadedWork
```

Now i am saving the combined bitmap (now in loadedWork) to file as follows:

try {

```
final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/SoftCopy" + "/mybitmap.png"));

            loadedWork.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            return true;
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

THE problem is that the combined bitmap(loadedWork) gets saved as png file for 1st time and i am able to load it, however WHEN I AGAIN TRY TO SAVE AFTER MAKING SOME MODIFICATIOns, then the application crashes. Can someone tell me how can I be able to resave the combined bitmap.

Comment: Actually I am new to android development. I dont know how to use logcat :s

Comment: At the bottom of Eclipse's window there is Logcat tab. Logcat output is printed there. Check what's in it after your application crashes and post error (marked red). Usually logcat output is self explainatory as it consists of error class, source code file and line and call stack.

Comment: On resaving, the application crashes and LogCat is indicating a problem at line
 
Canvas c= new Canvas(loadedWork);

Comment: Post whole error (Exception class, ...)

Comment: E   980   AndroidRuntime

Comment: Need whole line error log not fraction of it...

Comment: Caused by: java.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas Constructor at android.graphics.Canvas.<init> (Canvas.java:83) at neduet.telecom.softcopy.surface.SoftCopyInterface.getBitmap(SoftCopyInterface.java:128)

Actually SoftCopyInterface is a SurfaceView. And getBitmap() is a method defined in it to get the current contents of surface.

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
 
 
 Canvas c = new Canvas(loadedWork);
 c.drawBitmap(currentWork, 0, 0, null);
        return loadedWork;
 
 }

Comment: Now Google "Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas Constructor" (from logcat) gives you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693060/loading-a-resource-to-a-mutable-bitmap

Comment: Thanks alot Im0rtality.... my problem has solved =D