# How to get the Image size so i can edit text at bottom in android?

Tags: android, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to edit image for e.g. permanently adding text on the image which becomes the part of that image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384197/how-to-edit-image-for-e-g-permanently-adding-text-on-the-image-which-becomes-the)

my query is to get the size of the image and then i will edit at the bottom with the text.
let say i have image and i want to edit it at the bottom using text but i dont know the size as the picture is taken by the camera or may be from Sd card storage.
The problem is i can not give a static location in

```
canvas.drawText("Text",Xpos,Ypos,paint);
```

so just want size and according to that i will edit at the bottom by passing Xpos and Ypos in above methode.
Can anybody help me on that...?

Comment: explain a bit more. is your view taking the size of the image? is your image in an imageview?

Comment: see what i am doing is taking image from the camera and storing it to database and sending it to server. while capturing image from camera at that time i am editing it using canvas and paint. i am displaying it on the imageview but i dont know whether imageview is doing something wrong as in one of the case i am getting the text and in ohter case i am not getting text. i think this is all because i dont know the size of the image. so i want to change that image at runtime. Hope this explains my query if you still need more, i will post my code also. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the bitmap of the image using bitmap factory,decode file. Then use your_bitmap.getwidth() and your_bitmap.getheight().

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pavankumar Vijapur.                            jDourlens method works for me...

Answer (score 4):

When you have loaded your image as a `Bitmap` : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

You can access the methods wich will give you the height and the width of your image.

```
myBitmap.getHeight();
myBitmap.getWidth();
```

then just do:

```
canvas.drawText("Text",myBitmap.getWidth() - (lenghtOfText * sizeOfText) ,myBitmap.getHeight() - sizeOfText ,paint);
```

Comment: great man!! it works as i wanted. Thank you once again jDourlens..