# Get Bitmap from SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview

I need to convert my SurfaceView's content into a Bitmap. I tried to achieve this using the following code snippet inside the SurfaceView:

```
 public final Bitmap getScreenCopy() {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                getWidth(),
                getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        );

        Canvas temporaryCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        draw(temporaryCanvas); // Voodoo.

        return bitmap;
    }
```

The bitmap I receive from that drone seems to be transparent, does anyone know how to fix that?

Using a TextureView is not possible, since I use the Parrot SDK and the drone needs a SurfaceView to display the Frames.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: creating a Bitmap with SurfaceView content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742868/android-creating-a-bitmap-with-surfaceview-content)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181498/getting-bitmap-from-custom-surfaceview

Comment: I already checked that, did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to find a way to achieve this too and so far I haven't found a way to do it for devices with API level below 24. I tried messing with the drawing cache, but I get nothing but transparency. I didn't expect the *drawingCache* approach to work anyway due to the fact that the view itself draws nothing and everything goes onto the `Surface`.

For API levels 24 and newer, you can use the [PixelCopy APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy) to copy all or a portion of the `SurfaceView` into a bitmap.

Here's a snippet from my (Kotlin) code:

```
override fun getPlotBitmap(view: PlotSurfaceView) = Single.create<Bitmap> {
    val plotBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

    val listener = PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener { copyResult ->
        when (copyResult) {
            PixelCopy.SUCCESS -> {
                it.onSuccess(plotBitmap)
            }
            else -> {
                it.onError(RuntimeException("Pixel copy failed with result $copyResult"))
            }
        }
    }

    PixelCopy.request(view, plotBitmap, listener, view.handler)
}
```